# By using below code how can i delete image from folder in asp .net

Tags: c#, asp.net

```html
<asp:GridView ID="gvDisplayImages" runat="server" BackColor="#CCCCCC" 
        BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="3px" CellPadding="4" 
        CellSpacing="2" ForeColor="Black" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="intId"
        onrowdeleting="gvDisplayImages_RowDeleting" 
        onselectedindexchanged="gvDisplayImages_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField SelectText="Delete" ShowDeleteButton="true" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="varImageName" HeaderText="ImageName" 
                    SortExpression="varImageName" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Preview Image">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Image ID ="Img1" runat="server" Height="150" Width="200" ImageUrl='<%#ResolveUrl ("~/" + Eval("varImagePath")) %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#000099" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#808080" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#383838" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

code for cs page

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BindData();
}
public void BindData()
{
    gvDisplayImages.DataSource = bcObj.DisplayImages();
    gvDisplayImages.DataBind();
}
protected void gvDisplayImages_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    int intId = Convert.ToInt32(gvDisplayImages.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
    bcObj.DeleteImage(intId);
    BindData();
    string filename = Convert.ToString(gvDisplayImages.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Img1") as Image);
    string filepath = "\\Image\\" + filename;
    FileInfo file = new FileInfo(filepath);
    if (file.Exists)
    {
        file.Delete();
    }
}
```

Here I am using 3 tier architecture in asp .net By using above code while click delete button in gridview, images are deleted from database successfully. Now please tell me how should I delete image from folder where all images are stored.

Comment: You have already written code for file deletion from folder.

Comment: i know code is there but when i debug the code i can't get filename of image

Comment: Need to use `ImageUrl` in your code.

Comment: like this 
`string filename = ((Image)(gvDisplayImages.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Img1"))).ImageUrl;`

Comment: Since you attempt a 3-tier architecture : you may want to move the deletion of the file out of your presentation layer into your bcObj...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to use `ImageUrl` in your code.

like this

```
string filename = ((Image)(gvDisplayImages.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Img1"))).ImageUrl;
```

Comment: No its not working. If only one image is present at that time it gives error, if more images are present it gets id of another image

Comment: What do you really mean `if more images are present`? And whats the   error that you are getting?

Comment: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index

Comment: more images means more than one image

Comment: r u storing more than one images in each row or single image?

Comment: each row consists of only one image but folder where all the images are stored has more than one image

Comment: remove `BindData();` and put it at the end of `gvDisplayImages_RowDeleting` event.

And now tell me what is the value of `filename`
 `string filename = ((Image)(gvDisplayImages.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Img1"))).ImageUrl;`

Comment: according to your above instruction i had done work now value of filename is /imgUpld3tier/Image/ring.jpg. Here imgUpld3tire is name of my web application. Image is the folder name where all the images are stored and ring.jpg is name of the image. filepath shows \Image\/imgUpld3tier/Image/ring.jpg

Comment: Now do this:
`FileInfo file = new FileInfo(Server.MapPath("~"+filename));
    if (file.Exists)
    {
        file.Delete();
    } `

Comment: here no need of `filepath` variable.

Comment: now file shows this E:\study time\Arya\imgUpld3tier\imgUpld3tier\Image Here imgUpld3tier appears two times

Comment: `FileInfo file = new FileInfo(Server.MapPath(".."+filename)); if (file.Exists) { file.Delete(); } ` works for me